# MySQL "illegal mix of collations" using variable from source file

Tags: mysql, character, collation

I have the following in a .sql file:

```
SET @campaigns = "'9c943c24-f636-11e3-98bd-02f651afdab5','7ca1cf19-f562-11e3-98bd-02f651afdab5'";

select * from campaigns
  where id in (@campaigns);
```

Table `campaigns` is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaigns` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  # column defs snipped #
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I connect to my local MySQL instance via command line and attempt to execute the above file:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u usename -ppassword
mysql> use mydatabase;
mysql> source myfile.sql
```

I get the following error:

`ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`

If I alter the query to (I think) specify the collation:

```
select * from campaigns
where id COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci in (@campaigns);
```

The response is:

`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`
`Empty set (0.00 sec)`

If I drop the variable contents directly into the query:

```
select * from campaigns
where id in ('9c943c24-f636-11e3-98bd-02f651afdab5','7ca1cf19-f562-11e3-98bd-02f651afdab5');
```

I get the expected two results returned.

What's going on? I've read several Stack Overflow threads on MySQL *collation* and similar errors, and I'm still unable to fathom why my variable is not working as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax does not allow for `in (@campaigns)`, where `@campaigns` is a commalist of items.  You have essentially asked for one long string, not two as you hoped.  I don't think there is a way to do what you want (set an `@variable` to a list, then use it in an `IN`.)

To investigate why you got the error about collations, please provide

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';
```

Comment: Hi - Many thanks. I'll look into an alternative way to do my IN() query. Here's the char/collate settings:

`character_set_client  utf8`


`character_set_connection utf8`


`character_set_database  latin1`


`character_set_filesystem  binary`


`character_set_results  utf8`


`character_set_server  latin1`


`character_set_system  utf8`


`character_sets_dir   /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/charsets/`


`collation_connection utf8_general_ci`


`collation_database latin1_swedish_ci`

`collation_server latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: Fixing the `IN()` will (I think) make the collation problem go away.